# NoMethodError in Posts#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm doing the [Getting started with Rails tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and when I run the local server from shell I get this:

```
`NoMethodError in Posts#new` `/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
`undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

That is the extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
2:  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
3:  <div id="errorExplanation">
4:      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
```

I just started on Ruby on Rails and I can't figure out what is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message, you are seeing means that you have some variable that contains a `nil` object instead of the actual object you expect.

While the error message doesn't explicitly reference this, it is likely your `@post` variable is nil.

Why is it nil? That's near impossible to say given the code here. Please post your `PostsController#new` action as well.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I think is better if i put all that staff

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I think is better if i put all that stuff in other `question`. i'm reading the documentation again, and again i found some other features that i unkown. `Active model only run in Rails 4.0?`, holly b. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; I'm fairly sure `ActiveModel` has been a part Rails since the 3.x series.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is into  **posts_controller.rb**, add next code

def new
  **@post = Post.new**
end

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
// Make sure to use model declaration inside your method to check the error logs

class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new
@post = Post.new
end
```