# NoMethodError in Rails app, method 'error' undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a Rails blog app with [this tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16B202fDMObUX1_iVwiAYFxe7tEN0PiMYfq7RiNXb3oM/edit)

I am stuck on the step that validates that the fields a user enters are not empty. However, if I try to pass empty fields, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#create
Showing C:/Users/irowe/Documents/GitHub/Rails-Blog/blog/app/views/posts/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is my post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc)
end
def show
end
def new
@post = Post.new
end
def create
  p = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
  if p.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created a new post!'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Something went awry...'
    render :new
  end
end
end
```

and my "new post" view

```
<h1>New Post</h1>
<ul>
  <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= form_for @post, url: create_post_path do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<br />
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<br />
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :title
validates_presence_of :content
before_validation :preval
private
  def preval
  if self.title
    self.title = self.title.strip
  end
  if self.content
    self.content = self.content.strip
  end
end
end
```

I have seen other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557861/nomethoderror-in-postsnew) but they just recommend to make sure `post` is not `nil` , which I have made sure it isn't. Any ideas on how to make sure the validation woks? I am totally new to Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NilClass**

The error you're getting is standard if Rails is trying to manipulate an object which doesn't exist...

```
for nil:NilClass
```

For Ruby, there is no such thing as `Nil` - it translates it into a `NilClass` object. Thus, if you're trying to call the `errors` method on this object, it will raise an exception.

The error is with this line:

```
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```

Now, this won't be the *cause* of the error, just the symptom. It means that `@post` doesn't exist. To remedy this, you need to look at why:

```
def create
  p = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
  if p.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created a new post!'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Something went awry...'
    render :new
  end
end
```

With this, you need to do several things:

---

**Instance Variable**

You need to make an [*instance variable*](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/45-more-classes/lessons/110-instance-variables), which will then be available in the view:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new post_params
  if @post.save
```

This should allow your view to access the `@post` variable (which it wouldn't do it it were just local in scope).

**Conditional**

Secondly, you may wish to make the `errors` invocation conditional:

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
   <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
```

This should get it working for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your variable local into instances variable. To make instances variable, you can only add `@`. It means the variable can be used in your new.html.erb file. For example:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
  if @post.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created a new post!'
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Something went awry...'
    render :new
  end
end
```

This is good tutorial from rails guide [rails guide to get started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).
I hope this tutorial can help you a lot.

Comment: Actually, you're talking about instance variables. Global variables start with `$` sign. Look here for details on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495098/difference-between-various-variables-scopes-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks Alexey Shein. That's exactly that I want to say.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `create` action. In it, you are using the local variable `p` to store the `Post`. However, when the validations fail, your code renders the `new` view. That view is looking for the instance variable `@post`. So simply, change your code to this:

```
@post = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
  if @post.save
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you don't get the error when you open the `new` form, but only when you submit the form and it has errors.

That would be because you render the `new` form again here:

```
  flash[:alert] = 'Something went awry...'
  render :new
```

`render` simply renders the form, it does not redirect to the `new` action.
And you never set `post` in your `create` action.

An easy fix would be to change these two lines

```
p = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
if p.save
```

to this:

```
@post = Post.new(title: params[:post][:title], content: params[:post][:content])
if @post.save
```